# PHPExcel limit memory

Tags: php, phpexcel

Each time I try to export query results to Excel with PHPExcel class, I get those errors:

> PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 1293942784) (tried to
>   allocate 134217728 bytes) in ...\Classes\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php on
>   line 1218

With just a few rows, this work well, but now I have 130k rows and I don't know how to export this.

I tried with Cell Caching, but I get a error too:

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1686896640) (tried to allocate
>   131072 bytes) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\vinhos\Classes\PHPExcel\CachedObjectStorage\MemoryGZip.php
>   on line 49

With cache_in_memory the same error.

php.ini is configured with:

> memory_limit=-1

Comment: Cell caching doesn't mean "use no memory at all", it is simply a way of reducing memory requirements.... test the different options and find those that work best for you... SQLite or SQLite are the most memory efficient, but there is a speed trade-off in using cell caching

Comment: Note that cache_in_memory is the default, and stores absolutely everything in memory exactly "as is" so it is the least memory efficient

Comment: I've read in the past about PHPExcel being too lazy to release itself the memory after operations. Seems this isn't fixed yet.

Comment: How much memory is actually available for php on the server? Shared host or tiny vps might not have enough

Comment: Are you building large arrays in memory as well, e.g. fetching all your database results into an array and then writing them to PHPExcel?

Comment: @vlzvl - What operations should PHPExcel release memory after performing? As a harrassed developer, I'm open to suggestions from somebody who clearly knows better than me how it should have been written.

Comment: @Mark Baker, i read cases where simple creating/writing to xls files would not freed the memory after it. Simple cases. Say before operation the mem usage was 6.5MB after it will be ~65MB. Not sometihng specific. But its being 1,2 years from this version i was reading about. I was not meant to be offensive, just read about and that's all.

Comment: @vlzvl - Will test and verify that this evening, but the Writers should free up memory that they use when it is no longer required.... Sorry if I sounded harsh, but I get fed up with people criticising without providing the specifics of what they're criticising, or criticising without actually reporting issues to the developers... especially given the number of hours per day that I actually spend trying to improve PHPExcel

Comment: @Mark Baker, accept my apology as well, we're all spending hours in something :) [report](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/10032), [report 2](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/18229)

Answer (score 0):

Your script is using over 1.2Gb in memory and you want to give it more?

If you must get the data into Excel via PHP then maybe writing a line at a time to a CSV file might be a more sensible approach. Or pushing the data back into the database and fetching directly into Excel usnig ODBC.

Comment: Yes, 1.2Gb is too much...But is a script to run once a month.. :/